# How to manipulate data form microservice response in Java, Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a project in Spring Boot that has a microservice architecture. I needed to make a call from one microservice to another and with data that I get as response do something. I am very new to all microservice architecture and Spring Boot, so I figured I need a small push :)

So I have this class:

**HttpDataClient.java**

```
public class HttpDataClient implements DataClient{

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpDataClient.class);

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public HttpDataClient(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public DataResponse getData(String dataId) {
        try{
            JsonNode node = restTemplate.exchange(
                    String.format("/data/%s", dataId),
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    new HttpEntity<>(buildRequest(dataId), headers()),
                    JsonNode.class
            ).getBody();
            return dataResponse(node);
        }catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            String msg = String.format(
                    "Error getting data for dataId: %s",
                    dataId,
                    e.getStatusCode(),
                    e.getResponseBodyAsString());
            LOGGER.error(msg);
            return dataResponse.failed();
        }
    }

    private MultiValueMap<String, String> headers() {
        final LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> mv = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        mv.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        return mv;
    }

    private DataResponse dataResponse(JsonNode node) {
        return DataResponse.dataResponse(
                asString(node, "dataId"),
                asString(node, "author"),
                asString(node, "authorDataId"),
                asString(node, "serverSideDataId")
        );
    }

    private JsonNode buildRequest(String dataId) {
        ObjectNode root = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        root.put("dataId", dataId);
        return root;
    }
}
```

And the interface

```
public interface DataClient {

    DataResponse getData(String dataId);
}
```

And from this class when I get response I should be able to do next if `author` is "Philadelphia" then `athorDataId` and `serverSideId` are the same and if author is not "Philadelphia" then `athorDataId` and `serverSideId` are not the same.

For now, I have created this class:

```
public class DataResolver {

    private final HttpDataClient client;

    public DataResolver(HttpDataClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
}
```

And in this class, I should execute all of this:

> And from this class when I get response I should be able to do next if `author` is "Philadelphia" then `athorDataId` and `serverSideId` are the same and if author is not "Philadelphia" then `athorDataId` and `serverSideId` are not the same.

But I don't know how to start. I know I suppose to use client to get the response data. I am not sure how to use it.. And then I should probably do something like this :

```
if (author == Philadelphia) {
        authorDataId == serverSideDataId
    } elseif(author != Philadelphia) {
        authorDataId != serverSideDataId
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Is it possible to create new class like this

```
public class DataResolver {
        private final HttpDataClient client;
    
        public DataResolver(HttpDataClient client) {
            this.client = client;
        }
}
```

And in this class access data from response and manipulate it in some way?

Something like this:

```
public class DataResolver {
    private final HttpDataClient client;

    public DataResolver(HttpDataClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public DataIdResolver idResolver() {
        if (author == Philadelphia) {
            authorDataId == serverSideDataId
        } elseif(author != Philadelphia) {
            authorDataId != serverSideDataId
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the response that you expect should contain the mentioned attributes, then you should create the following class and use it as the return type in `restTemplate.exchange` instead of `JsonNode.class` (assuming you have Jackson in your classpath):

```
public class DataClient {
   private String dataId;
   private String author;
   private String authorDataId;
   private String serverSideDataId;

   // getters and setters
}
```

So you would have something like in the `HttpDataClient` class:

```
@Override
public DataClient getData(String dataId) {
    try{
        DataClient data = restTemplate.exchange(
                String.format("/data/%s", dataId),
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new HttpEntity<>(buildRequest(dataId), headers()),
                DataClient.class).getBody();
        return data;
    }catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        String msg = String.format(
                "Error getting data for dataId: %s",
                dataId,
                e.getStatusCode(),
                e.getResponseBodyAsString());
        LOGGER.error(msg);
        return dataResponse.failed();
    }
}
```

And `DataResolver`:

```
@Component
public class DataResolver {
   private final HttpDataClient client;

   public DataResolver(HttpDataClient client) {
      this.client = client;
   }

   public DataClient idResolver(String dataId) {
       DataClient data = client.getData(dataId);
       // Whatever logic you need
       return data;
   }
}
```

Maybe one important thing here is that you most likely would want to make `HttpDataClient` a Spring bean by adding the `@Service` annotation. By doing this you can autowire it to any other Spring bean you need.

Comment: And if I do save data in `DataClient` how can I access that data in the `HttpDataClient` class? And how to manipulate it in the way I explained in my question. And yes, I do have DataClient model class already existing.

Comment: I've edited my answer but I am not sure I fully understood your question in the comment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer yes that was close to something I was looking for. But my question is can I call `HttpDataClient` from another class for example called `DataResolver` and there get all the logic that I want for my data response. Please check my question update

Comment: Yes, you can definitely do that. But for that you might want to turn `HttpDataClient` and `DataResolver` into Spring Beans by adding the @Service or @Component annotation to both of them. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Ahaa okay, and how do I access for example `author` or any other filed in response? How do I access it in `public idResolver() { // Whatever logic you need}`

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I access it"? It is a regular public method as all other public methods. You need an instance of `DataResolver` and then call the method. By using `@Component` you are asking Spring to create an instance of it and handle it as a Spring bean. But that is Java and Spring basics.

Comment: Yes, and that method has api response which contains data like dataId, author, authorDataId and so on. So my question is how to access that data from idResolver method. I know how to call the method but how to call method and get data from it? I hope I explained good what I am looking for :)

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you. This was what I was looking for!